When to use redis rdb dump when aof is enabled?
From my understanding of Redis code, when server starts, it loads db from AOF file if AOF is enabled. Otherwise it tries to load from RDB dump.
https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/unstable/src/server.c#L6714
This means, if AOF is enabled and RDB file is present, RDB file is never used.
I wonder when do people enable both RDB and AOF?
How to make use of RDB file when AOF is enabled?

Normally AOF file is larger than RDB file, and it's much slower loading AOF file than RDB file.
So normally, we use RDB file for backup, and disaster recovery.

If AOF file is enabled, redis server will always load from AOF on startup. When is RDB file going to be used?

As I mentioned in the answer, you can backup the RDB file to HDFS, S3 or other storage. If the Redis server node is down, disk corrupted, you can recovery Redis with the backup RDB file.
